# Time Series Components wrt Multiplication and Addition

Tags: time-series, seasonality, trend

I was wondering whether a time series can be a combination of addition(+) and multiplication(*) of it's components.
For example

$$ TS = Trend(T) + Seasonality(S) + Local Pred(L) + Noise(N)$$

or

$$  TS =  T* S* L*N.$$

But, is it possible that the TS may be a combination of + and * ?
For example something like

$$ TS = T*(S+L+N)$$

or

$$ T*S+L+N$$

or something like this?

Comment: Hi: probably not. You can take the log of the LHS and then see what that gives you on the RHS. If it doesn't make sense, then that's your answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But if it is the first one, TS = T*(S+L+N), then TS/T = S+L+N. Doesn't this make sense ?

Comment: Hi: How do you defined local pred ? Not trying to be difficult but I don't see how the series divided by the trend gives something useful ? Hopefully someone else can chime in because I generally use additive models but full multiplicative could make sense. I don't think partial multiplicative and partial additive does but it's difficult for me to formulate a reason why. I'll think about it but, if it's urgent, I hope someone else replies.

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/46050/additive-vs-multiplicative-model-in-time-series-data. this explains things reasonably well. I don't have time to look for more things right now but google is everyone's friend.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I'm hoping someone else replies with a real answer.